# GraphQL with React-Apollo: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have the following gQL defined,

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

const SIGN_UP_QUERY = gql`
  query {
    signUpForm @client {
      firstName
      email
      password
    }
  }
`
```

and i use it with react-apollo query as such

```
<Query query={SIGN_UP_QUERY}>
    {({
      data: {
        signUpForm: { firstName }
      },
      loading
    }) => { ...... }}
</Query>
```

With this i am getting an error `Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined`

What is it that i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Current answers have some good ideas.  Please post the code where you're actually using the data so we can be sure.  You of course will want to make sure the data is being returned from your API successfully to begin with as well.

Answer (score 6):

You're de-structuring the `data` variable before it exists/has loaded. You should wait until loading = false before trying to access the data.

Comment: I think the problem is moreso in trying to access it than simply destructuring it. From what I understand, the destructuring he's doing could work successfully, but I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: De-structuring is a form of access. If the nested property doesn't exist, de-structuring an object will throw an error, the exact error he posted.

Comment: I'm able to destructure data before it's returned using the ```useQuery``` hook, however I do receive an error by trying to use it before it's loaded.  Maybe it works differently in a Query component.  I admit it may not be the best idea, and I need to placate TypeScript to do so, but, for example, this works: ```const { loading, error, data: {findAll}} = useQuery<any>(GET_FILERS);```. Nothing built-in to JS throws an error.

Answer (score 3):

Do you check if data has loaded yet?

```
if (loading) return "data not fetched yet";
return <p>{ firstName }</p>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are destructuring variables, you need to make sure that `data`, also `data.signUpForm` are null OR undefined.

Here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/apollo-local-cache-d3dm7) for your situation.

There are three problems can make `data/data.signUpForm` is not an object:

1. While loading the query, the data is `undefined`
2. After loading, the signUpForm is not available in the apollo cache
3. After loading, the signUpForm is available in the cache, but it's null

To resolve your problem:

1. Process data after loading and query is not returned any error
2. Make sure your data is available on the cache
3. Make sure your returned data have a correct structure